# change background position on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in this code changing the background position starts on body scrolling . i want to change background position when the scroll is on the background image

```js
$(function() {

  var rotator = $('#rotator');
  var container = $(document);
  var viewport = $(window);

  var images = 72;
  var imageHeight = 30000 / images;
  var scrollHeight = container.height() - viewport.height() + imageHeight;
  var step = images / scrollHeight;

  viewport.scroll(function(event) {

    var x = -Math.floor(step * viewport.scrollTop()) * imageHeight;
    rotator.css('background-position', x + 'px 0');

  });
});
```

```css
  body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#rotator {
  font-size: 416px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 580px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: transparent url(https://www.3sessanta.it/images/polaroid/sprite_polaroid_total.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotator"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add condition when the background change will start `if (viewport.scrollTop() > fixed_value)` then you need to remove this same value from calculation like this  :

```js
$(function() {

  var rotator = $('#rotator');
  var container = $(document);
  var viewport = $(window);

  var images = 72;
  var imageHeight = 30000 / images;
  var scrollHeight = container.height() - viewport.height() + imageHeight;
  var step = images / scrollHeight;

  viewport.scroll(function(event) {

    if (viewport.scrollTop() > 580) {
      var x = -Math.floor(step * (viewport.scrollTop() - 580)) * imageHeight;
      rotator.css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#rotator {
  font-size: 416px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 580px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: transparent url(https://www.3sessanta.it/images/polaroid/sprite_polaroid_total.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotator"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to change the background position when scroll is in middle of the page , i don't want to fixed the image

Comment: then wrap it in a condition based on `offset.top` & `window.scroll`

Comment: sorry but i don't know how can i do this . can you give me am example or edit my code ?

Comment: @lixex can you be more specific, actually your code is doing this no ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif no it doesn't . in my code when i scroll and see the image  the background position is on -6666.67px , i want when i sow image for the first time the background position be on 0 not -6666.67px

Comment: i think i should change viewport = $(window); but when i change it the code doesn't work at all

Comment: @lixex ah ok, got, you mean you want the animation to start when you reach the image, ok will update the answer

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function() {

  var rotator = $('#rotator');
  var container = $(document);
  var viewport = $(window);

  var images = 72;
  var imageHeight = 30000 / images;
  var scrollHeight = container.height() - viewport.height() + imageHeight;
  var step = images / scrollHeight;

  viewport.scroll(function(event) {

    if (viewport.scrollTop() > 580) {
      var x = -Math.floor(step * (viewport.scrollTop() - 580)) * imageHeight;
      rotator.css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#rotator {
  font-size: 416px;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 580px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: transparent url(https://www.3sessanta.it/images/polaroid/sprite_polaroid_total.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotator"></div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).